# Does the blood hunter gain an additional blood curse at level 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, dnd-beyond, blood-hunter

In the rules for Matt Mercer's [blood hunter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter) class on D&D Beyond, the description of the [Blood Maledict](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#BloodMaledict-1610580) feature (essentially using blood curses) states that you learn a blood curse when you gain the feature, and get one additional curse at 6th, 10th, 14th, and 18th level.

However, the [Blood Hunter table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/blood-hunter#TheBloodHunterTable) provided on D&D Beyond says you have 6 curses at level 20.

Does the blood hunter gain an additional blood curse at level 20 or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No, you don't gain access to a 6th blood curse at level 20. The table on D&D Beyond is incorrect.

This can be verified by "purchasing"<sup>1</sup> the [Blood Hunter class on DM's Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/301641/Blood-Hunter-Class-for-DD-5e-2020).

The table in this document does *not* show a 6th blood curse at level 20, and matches the description of the Blood Maledict feature instead.

## Note the difference compared with older versions of the Blood Hunter class:

DM's Guild has two different "Blood Hunter" classes; [one named "Blood Hunter Class for D&D 5e (2020)"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/301641/Blood-Hunter-Class-for-DD-5e-2020) and [one simply named "Blood Hunter Class"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170777/Blood-Hunter-Class).

The latter does grant you a 6th known blood curse at level 20 and *does* also reflect this in the Blood Maledict feature. In this version, however, you only gain the Blood Maledict feature at level 2, while both the 2020 version and the D&D Beyond version you linked in the question grant the feature at level 1.

Therefore, we can assume that the blood curse at level 20 listed in the table is left-over from the old version, while the rest of the document has been adapted to the 2020 version (hence the link in the first section of my answer links to that version).

<sub><sup>1</sup> you can choose what you want to pay, i.e. "paying" 0$ is possible</sub>

Comment: An interesting point is that I think every Blood Hunter *will* end up with six blood curses, because as far as I can see every subclass gives an extra blood curse at either 15th or 18th level, but these explicitly say they don't count against your total number known, so they don't interact with the table at all.